# React props(JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was implementing a basic rating component in React and somehow i did this

```
const Rating = ( {text},{value}) => {
return (
   <div className='rating'>
    <span>
        <i className={value>=1?'fas fa-star':value>=0.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':'far fa-star'}></i>
    </span>
    </div>
)}
```

instead of this

```
const Rating = ( {text,value}) => {
return (
   <div className='rating'>
    <span>
        <i className={value>=1?'fas fa-star':value>=0.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt':'far fa-star'}></i>
    </span>
    </div>
)}
```

Can anyone tell me why the value is not processed in the first part?

P.S. I am relatively new in the react/javascript field, so sorry if it's a very basic question.

Answer (score 2):

this means you are expecting **2 objects** as arguments.

```
( {text},{value} )
```

this means you are expecting a **single object** as argument.

```
({ text, value })
```

When you create a component, you are normally only expecting one object argument, which we normally call it props.

```
const Component = (props) => {}
```

If you are expecting to use the component this way

```
<Component text="I am text" value="I am value" />
```

Then you can expect to use ({ text, value }) to restructure the props. Which is equivalent to

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const { text, value } = props
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because this `({text},{value}) != ( {text,value}).`

when you do this `({text,value})`, you destructuring props.